# What options does a person of Church of England religion have if they are not sure if they were baptized in infancy, and can't prove it either way?

Tags: baptism, canon-law, church-of-england, paedobaptism

If a Church of England member has never been baptized, then there are [pathways to receive this sacrament](https://www.churchofengland.org/life-events/adult-baptism). You can only [be baptized once](http://www.stmaryswestmalling.org.uk/?page_id=71).

What happens if a Church of England member is *unsure* and *cannot prove either way* whether they were baptized in infancy? Can they be baptized now?

The usual sources of proof - certificate, parish registers - are unavailable or destroyed, and there is no-one living who would be able to recall the original baptism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This conundrum is resolved by the device of **Conditional Baptism**.

The Church of England states [thusly](https://www.churchofengland.org/prayer-and-worship/worship-texts-and-resources/common-worship/christian-initiation/baptism-and):

> **Conditional Baptism**
>
> If it is not certain whether a person has already been baptized with water in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit, then the usual service of baptism is used, but the form of words at the baptism shall be
>
> *N, if you have not already been baptized, I baptize you in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit.*